# Comparing File-names in git

Tags: git, git-diff

I have to compare all files in two different folders by file name only.
So far i just found the:

```
git diff --name-only
```

option, but this one shows me files that are changed as far as code goes. what i want to know, is which files were deleted from the newer folder and what their name is.

Comment: Are you comparing folders or repos? If it's folders why don't you just use a tool like [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)? If it's repos, is one of them remote or both local, etc?

Comment: they are both local. using winmerge would compare the content of the files afaik. what im interested in for example is, if file 1234.cpp in folder one is in folder two and has the same name. Im not exactly interested in the differences the files have, but which files got removed in development

Comment: [There are lots of tools that'll do this](https://superuser.com/questions/102063/compare-directories-on-windows). I don't think GIT is going to be your best option. Ultimately it's just comparing directories. The fact that those folders are also git repos is irrelevant.

Comment: thank you! im still kind of new to all of this.  ill look up what possibilities ive got here as far as diff-tools are concerned :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for list of files changed between two commits:

Use `--name-status`, it's the same as `--name-only` plus the status of changed files:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD~5 HEAD~3
```

to see the differences between the firth latest commit and the third latest.

This will give the history of files.

Comment: Hi Shivkumar. There's no need to reflexively add "hope this helps" to everything you post, since no-one posts hoping their answer does not help. It's redundant, and is likely to be removed by editors.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something I don't understand about your scenario, because it doesn't sound like git is the most straightforward tool for this task.[1]  That said, if you have a `git diff` command in mind that shows the list of changed files, you could add a `--diff-filter` option to limit the types of changes you see.

```
git diff --diff-filter=AD --name-only ...
```

You also might want to use the `--no-renames` option for a case like this, so that you just get a list of filenames that appear or disappear without git trying to guess at intention.

As you've noticed, `--name-only` option does not mean that diff only compares names; it only means that git will only *show* names.  You also could use `--name-status` instead of `--name-only`, and then it would tell you what type of change applies to each path (so you could look for the `A` and `D` changes).

---

[1] : What I mean is, it sounds like you're saying you have two different folders at one point in time and want to compare them.  While git is good at showing *changes to a directory tree over time,* it's not really a general-purpose diff tool.  What's wrong with

```
ls dir1 > filelist-1.txt
ls dir2 > filelist-2.txt
diff filelist-1.txt filelist-2.txt
```

instead?